# C# Cannot load XML document from server

Tags: c#, xml

I had an XMLDocument loading a document from a server with no problems till, almost randomly, I started getting a connection refused error.

It also doesn't matter what host I put in, whether it's a legit one or unresolvable. It always gives the same result.

Here's the code:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("http://doesnotmatterifIresolveornot.com");
```

And here is the error:

```
{"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888"}
```

I've turned off any applicable firewalls I can find in Win7, but it's weird cause it happened while I was testing it.

Comment: Hmm... 127.0.0.1:8888... seems that fiddler is still running... is that the intent? Maybe you left it running from another debug session, and you forgot to close it for testing that xml document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out why it's trying to go to 127.0.0.1:8888.

My *guess* is that for some reason, it thinks that's your HTTP proxy. Did you run something like Fiddler recently? Fiddler runs on 8888 and changes your default proxy settings - maybe they got stuck incorrectly?

Look in Control Panel, or in the Internet Explorer settings.

Comment: Even without fiddler open, it looked like the proxy server was redirecting still. Even with a reboot, it didn't work. I opened fiddler back up, saw that the "capturing" was still on. Unchecking that and retesting showed that it worked once again. 

I should have looked into with netstat,etc., but was lazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you serving your XML document using IIS? If so, you may need to add a mime-type definition to IIS to serve XML files.  [This](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx) article should help with that (if it is indeed the problem).

you may also try the HTTP loader to get a more detailed picture of what the server is responding with (HTTP headers, in particular, could be useful for troubleshooting).

I suspect the primary issue is that you're trying to connect to a socket (server + port) that the server isn't configured to listen on -- that means you'll get this error regardless of whether or not the URL resolves, since the server isn't configured to deal with a socket connection of the sort you're sending it.